# Is there an alternate "power" function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Numerics
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim term As BigInteger
        Const Phi As Double = (1 + (5 ^ 0.5)) / 2
        Const phi_ As Double = (1 - (5 ^ 0.5)) / 2

        For count As BigInteger = 2 To 99999999
            term = ((Phi ^ count) - (phi_ ^ count)) / (5 ^ 0.5)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: [Math.Pow(Double, Double) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8) - `Math.Pow(10, 2`

Comment: use Math.Pow(2, 2). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `Math.Pow` accepts `double` which should be enough ;)

Comment: No, finding a library that maintains accuracy for that many terms is hard shopping.  All that this code does is compute the Fibonacci sequence, that's very easy to do without floating point math.

Comment: What's the problem?  Is it that it won't compile, or is it with the results you get?  If the issue is with compiling, casting the exponents to double should work.  If the issue is with the results you get, you're going to need to find a quad-precision floating point as the issue will be that you're exceeding the range of integers that is exactly representable by a double.

Comment: The task was to find the term of the first Fibonacci sequence with 1000 digits, thus the need for a large data type, and the error was that after around 500 terms the BigInteger came up with an error claiming that it can't hold infinity. My belief is that the powers within the function are creating a too big of a number.Since then I have changed the code with a new formula which just calculates the number of digits it would have straight off from the term and it works much better.

Comment: OK, then I think the issue with the formula you used is that you were exceeding the range of the `Double` data type.  As such, your solution of using a different formula is the best approach; the only way to make the existing formula work would have been to use greater precision floating point (possibly arbitrary precision), as the alternative that was suggested by several others would have been no different than the `^` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Import `System` namespace and use `Math.Pow(double x, double y)` function. Details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why would you expect this to work differently from the `^` operator?

Comment: I would not. The question was about the alternative and I answered the question. Whether the question is of a high quality is a completely different story.